# extract private key from .pem file

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, jwt, pem

I want my code to extract private key from my pem file .

My pem file looks like this -> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- some encrypted code -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- .

I have the same code in ruby but i'm not able to do this in javascript.

[image: I have the same code in ruby but i'm not able to do this in javascript]

Comment: Please add your code as text to your question (and pay attention to [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)). There are [many good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), why images of code are not a good idea.

Comment: I came across this question when I was also attempting to transliterate the quoted snippet of code from Ruby to JavaScript. It comes from [Authenticating as a GitHub App](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps#authenticating-as-a-github-app), for those who may be interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const fs = require("fs");

var myKey = fs.readFileSync("mykey.pem", "utf8").replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "").replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "").trim();

console.log("My key is: ", myKey);
```

Keep in mind, this will only work if there is one key in the file instead of a list of keys, but you should get the gist.

Comment: i cant use replace on readFIleSync because Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'Buffer'

Answer (score 2):

For those looking to [Authenticate as a GitHub App](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps#authenticating-as-a-github-app), in a [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) 14 context:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const privatePem = fs.readFileSync('github-app-private-key.pem');
const privateKey = crypto.createPrivateKey({
  key: privatePem,
});
```

I was then able to pass `privateKey` to [jose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jose) SignJWT's [`sign` method](https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/main/docs/classes/jwt_sign.SignJWT.md#sign).